# How to Hit Frank Wests' Servbot Head Hyper Combo?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

I just started playing *Ultimate Marvel vs Capcom 3*, and I started to play Frank West because I was a big fan of *Dead Rising*. Whilst in training mode messing around figuring out his kit, for some reason I cannot hit the hyper combo where he puts a servbot head on his opponent and beats them to a pulp. I either just land in front of them or miss them completely, and its aggravating that there's probably something simple that I am missing but cannot seem to figure it out.

Anyone out there more adept at this game and can tell me what I am missing in my button mashing quest to kill comic book characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most documentation I've seen it referred to as the "Funny Face Crusher" Hyper Combo.

**It is only available at or above Photography Level 3. It is an air grab move so your opponent must be airborne in order for Frank to perform this attack. It is performed with a Z on the directional control starting with forward (towards your opponent) (forward, Down, Down-Forward) followed by 2 attack buttons.**

These details can be found on the [character guide](http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2011/nov/14/frank-west-marvel-vs-capcom-3-moves-combos-strategy-guide/) and on [the wikia](http://wiki.shoryuken.com/Ultimate_Marvel_vs_Capcom_3/Frank_West#Level_3_and_Above) (where they oddly call it "Funny Face Circuit")

> This Hyper is not mashable but you can actually net more hits and damage by spinning the joystick around repeatedly during the giant swing animation. Funny Face Crusher leaves the opponent in an untechable knockdown state and Frank can actually continue to combo after this move by using the heavy version of Tools of Survival...
>
> When continuing a combo after Funny Face Crusher, always remember that the Hyper will leave you on the opposite side of where you started...